# In-app purchase not completed but users were charged

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, ios9

I've been getting some reports from our users that we're charging them but not creating the account for them.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self didPurchaseTransaction:transaction queue:queue];
                break;
```

and on the didPurchaseTransaction method, I store the logs to the server.

but I'm not getting the logs from these users. So for some reason, that didPurchaseTransaction were never called. We asked for their receipt from Apple, and we verified that we actually charge them.

This issues are not consistent as I'm never able to reproduce it myself. But every week or two, we get these reports. Anyone experienced this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: When do you call `finishTransaction` - you should not do so until you have confirmed that the account was created. What happens if the users restore their purchase?

Comment: apparently this is a known issue. I've found some people having the same issues. Apple rep also confirmed this problem. The issue is happening if the user has to be taken out of the app to update the payment information during the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is a known issue. I've found some people having the same issues. Apple rep also confirmed this problem. The issue is happening if the user has to be taken out of the app to update the payment information during the transaction. Upon completion it's not sending the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased status.